# Facebook: Viewing how many users have approved a particular permission

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

Where can I view the list of permissions that my users have approved?

Initially my app did not request the `publish_actions` perms and last week we started asking for the perms.

**Where can I view the stats related to this perm?** – the number who have approved, declined etc.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you head to your app settings, there's an insights tab, under that there's a growth option, which details Auth Dialog conversion and permission sets etc. Should be all the data you need.

[image: Permission Groups]

It's also accessible via the [API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/#analytics) if you want to hook those metrics into some internal dashboards.

Comment: Thanks for this. Whats does Permission set 2, 3 indicate?

Comment: Everytime you run a different set of permissions, we split it out into sets. Think of them as a/b test group. Allows you to see which combinations work best.

Comment: Thank for the detailed clarification.    
I am a bit confused. I have my app that requested only minimal perms till last week. But I started requesting the publish actions perms http://d.pr/i/Fiu0 and in the permission 2 I see very low CTR. But that refers to only publish_actions. What could be this?   
Is this my current permission request?

Comment: @ColmDoyle, do you know if this data is still available for apps? It's super useful and I can't find it anywhere.