# Still possible to view how many users have approved a particular group of permissions via Facebook Insights?

Tags: facebook, permissions

Is Facebook app Permission groups data still available via Insights?

This is described here ([Facebook: Viewing how many users have approved a particular permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13392149/facebook-viewing-how-many-users-have-approved-a-particular-permission)) but I don't see it when I go into Insights anymore.

This was really useful and I'm hoping it still exists via Insights (have not yet validated whether we can get it via the API). Has anyone seen it?